# How to extract certain csv data based on the header in python

Tags: python, csv

How would I extract specific data from a csv file, based on the header in python?
For example, say the csv file contained this information:

```
Height,Weight,Age
6.0,78,25
```

How could I retrieve just the age in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I second the `csv` recommendation, but I think here using `csv.DictReader` would be simpler:

(Python 2):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open("hwa.csv", "rb") as fp:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
...     data = next(reader)
...     
>>> data
{'Age': '25', 'Weight': '78', 'Height': '6.0'}
>>> data["Age"]
'25'
>>> float(data["Age"])
25.0
```

Here I've used `next` just to get the first row, but you could loop over the rows and/or extract a full column of information if you liked.

Comment: Nice, I'd never even heard of DictReader before.

Answer (score 2):

The process to follow is: read in the first line, find the index (location) on that line of the data you're looking for, then use that index to pull the data out of the remaining lines.

Python offers a very helpful `csv.reader` class for doing all the reading, so it's quite simple.

```
import csv

filename = 'yourfilenamehere'
column = 'Age'

data = [] # This will contain our data

# Create a csv reader object to iterate through the file
reader = csv.reader( open( filename, 'rU'), delimiter=',', dialect='excel')

hrow = reader.next() # Get the top row
idx = hrow.index(column) # Find the column of the data you're looking for

for row in reader: # Iterate the remaining rows
    data.append( row[idx] )

print data
```

Note that the values will come out as strings. You can convert to int by wrapping the `row[idx]` e.g. `data.append( int( row[idx] ) )`